# Best way to plot smooth normal distribution in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution

I would like to plot a nice, 'approaching the limit'-looking normal pdf in ggplot.

I found that to get a very symmetric and clean looking plot, I had to crank up the number of samples to a rather large number; one million creates a great visualization.  However, this is pretty slow, especially if I hope to work with Shiny at some point.

```
df <- data.frame(c(rnorm(1000000)))
ggplot(df, aes(df[1])) + geom_density()
```

Surely there is a better way to display something close to the ideal normal distribution?

Comment: does it have to be randomly sampled? or can you plot `dnorm`? like the first example here http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_function.html

Comment: From the `stat_function` helpfile: `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 5)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = dnorm)`

Comment: Thanks guys, I haven't come across `stat_function` before. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your code should look like:

```
 ggplot(data=dataset, aes(dataset$value)) +
      stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mean = mean(dataset$value), sd = sd(dataset$value)))
```

`stat_function` uses the `dnorm` function (to get the density of a normal variable) parses in the mean & median values and plots the normal distribution.

Reference : [How dnorm works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483064/how-dnorm-works)

For ggplot `stat_function` Documentation follow this [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.1.1/topics/stat_function)
Sample : https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-function.r